# Global Variables between scripts

Tags: python, scripting, namespaces, global-variables, scope

I have a python project with few scripts run by .sh shell files.

I have a config file  which defines a dictionary to be used across scripts.

**config.py**

```
name_dict = dict()
```

**file1.py**

```
from config import *
..
..

## I have that reads tries to load the dump file that will contain the json values. 

name_dict = json.load(open(dict_file))

##This file - file1.py calls another function fun() in file2.py, iteratively 3/4 times. 
..    
file2.fun(args)
print "Length of dict in file1.py : %d " %len(name_dict) // Always Zero ??? Considers name_dict as local variable.
```

In file2 - **file2.py**, I have defined name_dict with global keyword.fun() uses and updates the name_dict and finally I print the length of the dict at the start and I find it to be updated.

```
def fun(args)    
    global name_dict
    print "Length of dict file2.py(start): %d " %len(name_dict)
    ..
    ..
    print "Length of dict file2.py(end): %d " %len(name_dict)
```

Every time after the control returns from file2, In file1.py I print the value of **name_dict** and it is zero. But, in the next call to fun() -> the print statement still prints the global value(length) of name_dict()

But in file1.py it is always zero. My guess is it is treated as a local variable. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does **not** have global variables. The variables are all enclosed in modules, hence you could say that what you defined are module-level variables.

In order to modify a module variable you must assign it to the module:

```
#file1.py
import config

config.name_dict = json.load(...)
```

Doing:

```
from config import *

name_dict = json.load(...)
```

simple creates a *new* `name_dict`, module-level variable and assigns a new object to it, it does *not* change anything in the `config` module.

Also note that the `global` statement tells python that the given name should not be treated as a local variable. For example:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> def function():
...     x = 1
... 
>>> function()
>>> x
0
>>> def function():
...     global x
...     x = 1
... 
>>> function()
>>> x
1
```

It does *not* mean that you can access `x` from other modules.
Also it is useful only when *assigning* to a variable:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> def function():
...     return x + 1
... 
>>> function()
1
>>> def function():
...     global x
...     return x + 1
... 
>>> function()
1
```

As you can see you can reference the module-level `x` without saying that it is a `global`. What you cannot do is doing `x = something` and change the module-level variable value.

Comment: Hence, does it mean everytime I use name_dict (in file1 or file2) I should use config.name_dict (using its namespace)?

Comment: @Learner No. You can do `name_dict = config.name_dict` and use `name_dict` but when you do the assignments that should be communicated to other modules you will have to do that. Anyway I think it's quite rare to use this kind of pattern between module, so you may be able to simply refactor the code and avoid this.

Comment: Also, `from config import *` in file1 should import all the variables(including name_dict) defined in config.py right ? That is what I have been thinking. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Learner Yes. The `*` behaves like a "wild-card" in the shell. You can limit what the `import *` exports defining an `__all__` variable in `config` listing the names of the variables you want to export.

Comment: Oh I see. Also, I tried this loading my name_dict in my config.py file and using them in my file1.py and file2.py. Would this be a better approach ? What do you think

Comment: @Learner It depends from the application. If you always want to load that json object then it makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

len(name_dict.items)

#this will not be zero

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does this have to do with the question? Please read [answer].